# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string. Cannot find error

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

I'm writing a script to parse a larger file into usable data. I will attach the script below. The script was not running as I wanted and I thought it might have been the if/then statement I used, but when I took that off it revealed the real problem. This is now the error I am getting which makes it seem like the real problem is a quote mark of some kind.

```
FirstName,LastName,Company,Address,City,County,State,ZIP,Phone,Fax,Email,Web
FinalProject.sh: 36: FinalProject.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

While I technically understand what the syntax error means, I cannot find where the problem is, and I have been trying to fix it for about half an hour. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=${IFS}
IFS=$'\n'

head -1 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g'
for LINE in 'grep WV 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F, '{print $(NF-11)"," \ 
    $(NF-10)"," \ 
    $(NF-9)"," \ 
    $(NF-8)"," \ 
    $(NF-7)"," \ 
    $(NF-6)"," \ 
    $(NF-5)"," \ 
    $(NF-4)"," \ 
    $(NF-3)"," \ 
    $(NF-2)"," \ 
    $(NF-1)"," \
    $NF \ 
}''
 do
    FNAME='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $1}''
    LNAME='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $2}''
    COMPANY='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $3}''
    ADDRESS='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $4}''
    CITY='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $5}''
    COUNTY='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $6}''
    STATE='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $7}''
    ZIP='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $8}''
    PHONE='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $9}''
    FAX='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $10}''
    EMAIL='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $11}''
    WEB='echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $12}''
 done
```

Comment: I think you need to review your [syntax for command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution#Syntax_and_semantics)

Comment: the grep pipeline should be in back quotes not single quotes, as should each of the echo pipelines in the body of the loop

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are using single quotes `'...'` to wrap "command execution", which should be wrapped with back-quotes `` `...` ``, or (much better) `$(...)`.

That makes the line that start with: `for LINE in 'grep` and ends with
`}''` fail.
Making the minimum possible changes, the code becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=${IFS}
IFS=$'\n'

head -1 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g'
for LINE in `grep WV 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F, '{print $(NF-11) "," \
    $(NF-10)"," \
    $(NF-9)"," \
    $(NF-8)"," \
    $(NF-7)"," \
    $(NF-6)"," \
    $(NF-5)"," \
    $(NF-4)"," \
    $(NF-3)"," \
    $(NF-2)"," \
    $(NF-1)"," \
    $NF \
}'`
do
    FNAME=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    LNAME=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    COMPANY=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $3}'`
    ADDRESS=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $4}'`
    CITY=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $5}'`
    COUNTY=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $6}'`
    STATE=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $7}'`
    ZIP=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $8}'`
    PHONE=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $9}'`
    FAX=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $10}'`
    EMAIL=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $11}'`
    WEB=`echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $12}'`
done
```

---

However, it is a mistake to try to [process a file with a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/2350426), you should [use `read` to get the output of `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16317961/2350426):

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=${IFS}
IFS=$'\n'

head -1 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g'
while IFS=$'\n' read -r LINE
do
    FNAME="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
    LNAME="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $2}')"
    COMPANY="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $3}')"
    ADDRESS="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $4}')"
    CITY="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $5}')"
    COUNTY="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $6}')"
    STATE="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $7}')"
    ZIP="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $8}')"
    PHONE="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $9}')"
    FAX="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $10}')"
    EMAIL="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $11}')"
    WEB="$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F, '{print $12}')"
done < <(
    grep WV 50000_a.csv | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F, '{print $(NF-11) "," \
    $(NF-10)"," \
    $(NF-9)"," \
    $(NF-8)"," \
    $(NF-7)"," \
    $(NF-6)"," \
    $(NF-5)"," \
    $(NF-4)"," \
    $(NF-3)"," \
    $(NF-2)"," \
    $(NF-1)"," \
    $NF \
    }'
)
```

Comment: why is `$()` "much better" than back quotes?

Comment: @MurrayJensen Because it becomes very clear where a "Command Execution starts and ends.

Comment: I think it confuses things between variable expansions and command substitutions ... back quotes is very clear IMO

Comment: @MurrayJensen Exparience has shown that backticks are more dificult to use:[`The second form `COMMAND` is more or less obsolete for Bash, since it has some trouble with nesting ("inner" backticks need to be escaped) and escaping characters. Use $(COMMAND), it's also POSIX! `](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Comment: `echo ${LINE} | awk `{print $n}'` squashes any consecutive whitespace and can delete some leading tokens from the first field.
Assuming you actually want all fields as-is, it's much simpler (and faster) to just do `while IFS=, read -r FNAME LNAME COMPANY etc etc`.
Or if all input lines contain at least 12 fields, skip the `awk` to select NF-11 etc, use `read -r LINE; IFS=,; set -- $LINE; shift $#-12` then just use `FNAME=$1; LNAME=$2;` etc.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, just that this is not code I wrote. I made the least amount of simple changes so the poster could understand the problem(s).